# Migrate users to with a Lambda Trigger with AWS Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, react-native, kotlin, aws-sdk

I'm trying to migrate users from our existing user management system into our user pool without a password reset using the AWS-SDK for Android.

For iOS I found [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-ios-sdk-user-migration-lambda.html) which explains that adding a boolean to the awsconfiguration.json with the key `MigrationEnabled` and value `YES` should do the magic. This works.

For Android I found [an example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-android-sdk-user-migration-lambda.html) which totally doesn't match our Kotlin setup. For Android we're also using the awsconfiguration.json, but the `MigrationEnabled` boolean is not doing any magic in this case. Unfortunately with the above documentation I can't figure out how to do this in our Android app.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?